# choosing metric for R keras for imbalanced binary class

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes, keras

i am using Keras on a text classification task in RStudio.

I have a very imbalanced binary classification problem where the positive class is only present in about 2% of cases.

If i use down-sampling and only take 2% of the negative cases, i can achieve over 90% accuracy on my validation set with both 90% specificity and 90% sensitivity, however I would like to know if there is a way to use the entire dataset and a metric like F1 or Kappa instead of accuracy to cope with the imbalance.

This is my model currently (used on downsample data):

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
   layer_embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = 16) %>%
   layer_global_average_pooling_1d() %>%
   layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>% 
   layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") %>% 
 compile(
      optimizer = 'adam',
      loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
      metrics = c('accuracy')
  )
```

Is there a way i could replace metrics = c('accuracy') with F1 or Kappa, or both Sensitivity and Specificity?

Comment: Don't know about the metrics question (although I do know that accuracy is a poor metric for logistic regression)  but you do have other options for the imbalance problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103972/how-does-keras-uses-class-weight-parameter

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with an outcome with a very low prevalence, it is not appropriate to use classifiers but rather to model *tendencies*, i.e., probabilities.  There are several proper accuracy scores for probability forecasts.  The issues with classification are discussed in detail [here](http://fharrell.com/post/classification) and in other blog articles on that site.